# problem in memory allocation for strcture array?

Tags: c

```
int unsigned long size=(atoi(argv[2]))+1;

printf("\nthe size is %lu",size);
printf("\n am here 1");

if( (what_if_var=malloc((size)*sizeof(what_if)))== NULL)
{
    exit( -1 );
}

if((temp_var =malloc((size)*sizeof(what_if)))== NULL)
{
    exit( -1 );
}
```

when I give `argv[2]` as 367000 the memory allocation working fine, but when I gave `argv[2]` as more than 380000 the program got exit? is there is any other way to achieve this?

Comment: `int unsigned long` **UGH!** Please use the same order as everybody else :) `unsigned long int` or simply `unsigned long`. Your order is unexpected, but not a problem though.

Comment: Assuming you are using `argv[2]` as the number of bytes to allocate, should probably be able to get 380k. You should check the value of `errno` if `malloc` fails. There is a utility function, `perror` which should tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

These details depend on malloc's implementation, I don't think you can change them. Perhaps increasing your heap's size might help.

Answer (score 1):

> [edited] is there a way to allocate large number of bytes?

Buy more RAM.
Find another algorithm that can work with smaller chunks of data.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Shickadance suggested, **perror()** should help track down why **malloc()** fails.  This code demonstrates usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N_ARRAYS        2

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char * my_arrays[N_ARRAYS];
    size_t  nbytes = 1024;
    int i;

    if (argc>1) {
        nbytes = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (nbytes == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Parse error for input \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<N_ARRAYS; i++) {
        my_arrays[i] = malloc(nbytes);
        if (!my_arrays[i]) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            printf("[%i] Successfully allocated %i bytes on the heap\n", i, nbytes);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can pass in the number of bytes to allocate as argv[1].

On my Linux box, I can happily allocate up to a total of 2GB for the process, which is the default virtual address space size on my machine.  If I try to exceed that limit, **malloc()** fails and perror() tells me why:

```
# Allocate two 1024MB arrays
tom@gibbon:~/src/junk/stackoverflow$ ./a.out $((1024*1024*1024))
[0] Successfully allocated 1073741824 bytes on the heap
[1] Successfully allocated 1073741824 bytes on the heap
# Allocate two 1500MB arrays
tom@gibbon:~/src/junk/stackoverflow$ ./a.out $((1500*1024*1024))
[0] Successfully allocated 1572864000 bytes on the heap
malloc: Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you reached the limit of memory usage for your process.

The OS limit the amount of memory one can allocate in a single application.

There are many ways to over come this problem, but it depends on your needs:

1. Split the work to parts: each time allocate few memory, work with it, then reuse (or reallocate) the memory for the next part
2. Split the work with more than one process, those processes can share information to share the work
3. Implement your own paging mechanism: Create one or more files to store your memory and use them as your memory
4. More...

Please note the overhead of each solution